# How to clear array links after ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have next code for map some js object to model

```
...
      self.mydata= ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonobj));
...
```

inside of jsonobj I have other json array property (myarr property).

I need send this data to WCF service after changes but *myarr* must be empty
I do next:

```
var tempobj =  ko.toJS(self.mydata);
tempobj.myarr = null;//possible huge data         
        var data = { "p1": JSON.stringify(tempobj ) };
```

but after *JSON.stringify(tempobj)* i see that mydata property is empty, but string value contains data from  *mydata* array, it looks like references is still alive. 
how to remove all this data ?

thanks.

UPDATE 1
it looks all this data inside ***ko_mapping*** property.

Comment: Any chance of a http://jsfiddle.net to play around with?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found solution use ko.mapping.toJS inseted ko.toJS  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/6dEorpiyOzY

Answer (score 1):

I've made a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc6GF/) but I'm not entirely sure what your intention is.  Are you trying to clear the array or remove it from the object?

Both are done in the provided fiddle.

```
var model = {
    p1: [
        { id: 1, text: 'one' },
        { id: 2, text: 'two' }
    ]
};

// do you mean clear the array before sending?
//model.p1 = [];

// or do you mean remove the array before sending?
//delete model.p1;

document.getElementById('json').innerText = ko.toJSON(model);
```

Comment: Hi, I mean clear the array before sending model.p1 = []. but in your exampe you don't use ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonobj)); and this is working

Comment: It's not very clear what you're doing here, `ko.mapping` creates observables for you - so to have this in an observable is incorrect.  Can you provide a cut down example of the JSON you're deriving your model from?

Comment: I need get JSON object from model(clear observable). but it looks like i find solution i need use ko.mapping.toJS inseted ko.toJS https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/6dEorpiyOzY

Comment: What model??? What does your model look like??? You haven't provided enough information, so I have no idea what your model looks like.